# How to view paging system (demand paging) as another layer of cache?

Tags: caching, operating-system, mmu, swapfile, demand-paging

*I tried solving the following question*

---

**Consider a machine with 128MiB (i.e. 2^27 bytes) of main memory and an MMU which has a page size of 8KiB (i.e.2^13 bytes). The operating system provides demand paging to a large spinning disk.
Viewing  this  paging  system  as  another  layer  of  caching  below  the  processor’s  last-level  cache (LLC), answer following questions regarding the characteristics of this “cache”:**

**Line size in bytes?** 2^13 (every page has 2^13 bytes)

**Associativity?** Full Associative

**Number of lines in cache?** 2^14 (Memory size / page size)

**Tag size in bits?** 14 (Number of lines in cache is 2^14 which gives us 14 bits for tag)

**Replacement policy?** I am not sure at all (maybe clock algorithm which approximates LRU)

**Writeback or write-through?** write back (It is not consistent with Disk at all times)
**Write-allocate?** yes, because after page fault we bring the page to memory for both writing and reading

**Exclusivity/Inclusivity?** I think non-inclusive and non exclusive (NINE), maybe because memory mapped files are partially in memory and partially in swap file or ELF file (program text). Forexample stack of process is only in memory except when we run out of memory and send it to a swap file. Am I right?

---

*I would be glad if someone checked my answers and help me solve this correctly, Thanks! Sorry, if this is not the place to ask these kind of questions*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To start; your answers for line size, associativity and number of lines are right.

> Tag size in bits? 14 (Number of lines in cache is 2^14 which gives us 14 bits for tag)

Tag size would be "location on disk / line size", plus some other bits (e.g. for managing the replacement policy). We don't know how big the disk is (other than "large").

However; it's possibly not unreasonable to work this out backwards - start from the assumption that the OS was designed to support a wide range of different hard disk sizes and that the tag is a nice "power of 2"; then assume that 4 bits are used for other purposes (e.g. "age" for LRU). If the tag is 32 bits (a very common "power of 2") then it would imply the OS could support a maximum disk size of 2 TiB ("1 << (32-4) * 8 KiB"), which is (keeping "future proofing" in mind) a little too small for an OS designed in the last 10 years or so. The next larger "power of 2" is 64 bits, which is very likely for modern hardware, but less likely for older hardware (e.g. 32-bit CPUs, smaller disks). Based on "128 MiB of RAM" I'd suspect that the hardware is very old (e.g. normal desktop/server systems started having more than 128 MiB in the late 1990s), so I'd go with "32 bit tag".

> Replacement policy? I am not sure at all (maybe clock algorithm which approximates LRU)
>
> Writeback or write-through? write back (It is not consistent with Disk at all times) Write-allocate? yes, because after page fault we bring the page to memory for both writing and reading

There isn't enough information to be sure.

A literal write-through policy would be a performance disaster (imagine having to write 8 KiB to a relatively slow disk every time anything pushed data on the stack). A write back policy would be very bad for fault tolerance (e.g. if there's a power failure you'd lose far too much data).

This alone is enough to imply that it's some kind of custom design (neither strictly write-back nor strictly write-through).

To complicate things more; an OS could take into account "eviction costs". E.g. if the data in memory is already on the disk then the page can be re-used immediately, but if the data in memory has been modified then that page would have to be saved to disk before the memory can be re-used; so if/when the OS needs to evict data from cache to make room (e.g. for more recently used data) it'd be reasonable to prefer evicting an unmodified page (which is cheaper to evict). In addition; for spinning disks, it's common for an OS to optimize disk access to minimize head movement (where the goal is to reduce seek times and improve disk IO performance).

The OS might combine all of these factors when deciding when modified data is written to disk.

> Exclusivity/Inclusivity? I think non-inclusive and non exclusive (NINE), maybe because memory mapped files are partially in memory and partially in swap file or ELF file (program text). Forexample stack of process is only in memory except when we run out of memory and send it to a swap file. Am I right?

If RAM is treated as a cache of disk, then the system is an example of single-level store (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-level_store ) and isn't a normal OS (with normal virtual memory - e.g. swap space and file systems). Typically systems that use single-level store are built around the idea of having "persistent objects" and do not have files at all. With this in mind; I don't think it's reasonable to make assumptions that would make sense for a normal operating system (e.g. assume that there are executable files, or that memory mapped files are supported, or that some part of the disk is "swap space" and another part of the disk is not).

However; I would assume that you're right about "non-inclusive and non exclusive (NINE)" - inclusive would be bad for performance (for the same reason write-through would be bad for performance) and exclusive would be very bad for fault tolerance (for the same reason that write-back is bad for fault tolerance).

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I thought also that for cache tag, we need the Disk Size, which is not given in the question. And overall the question is very vague.